# Why is chunking with multithread so much more efficiënt?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, python-3.7, python-multiprocessing

So I made a code to search for primes. I wanted to test what was faster:

multiprocessing without chunking

single threaded

multiprocessing with chunking.

So anyway I made this code:

```py
def prime(n):
    if n == 2:
        return n
    if n & 1 == 0:
        return None
    
    d= 3
    while d * d <= n:
        if n % d == 0:
            return None
        d= d + 2
    return n

loop = range(2,1000000)
chunks = range(1,100000,1000)
def chunker(chunk):
    ret = []
    r2 = chunk + 1000
    r1 = chunk
    for k in range(r1,r2):
        ret.append(prime(k))
    return ret
    
from multiprocessing import cpu_count
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool
from time import time as t
pool = Pool(12)
start = t()
results = pool.map(prime, loop)
print(t() - start)
pool.close()
filtered = filter(lambda score: score != None, results)


new = []
start = t()
for i in loop:
    new.append(prime(i))
print(t()-start)
pool = Pool(12)
start = t()
results = pool.map_async(chunker, chunks).get()
print(t() - start)
pool.close()
```

And I got some interesting results:

```
multithread no chunks:
4.975985050201416
single thread:
5.060522556304932
multithread with chunks:
0.2060391902923584
```

Why is this sooo much faster? I am sure I have made a mistake somewhere but I can't find where.

Can anyone explain why it is so much faster or what mistake I made?

Comment: You're missing a `0` here `chunks = range(1,100000,1000)`.

Comment: If you type large numbers out as `chunks = range(1,100_000,1000)` versus `loop = range(2,1_000_000)`, it's easier to notice. Also, comparing the output of each of the versions makes it more apparent.